# How do I install Java JNA in Ubuntu server 14?

Tags: java, ubuntu

I'm trying to install the java native library from the command line as

```
sudo apt-get install libjna-java
```

but Ubuntu tells me

```
 E: Unable to locate package libjna-java
```

and even if I do cache search, there is nothing there matching that package.

How do I install Java JNA in Ubuntu server 14?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libjna-java is in universe repository and it seems that you dont have it enabled.
To enable, run

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```